# Internet access issue in Android 2.1 emulator (Windows 7 x86)

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-virtual-device

Anyone got this problem before?

`In Windows 7 x86`,

I created an avd which the target is `Android 2.1.`

It turns out that the emulator can not access the internet through the web browser.

But it works fine when the target is `Android 2.2`.
I've tried to set the proxy.  It just does not work in the Android 2.1 emulator.

Comment: While launching AVD , try deleting user data and launch again.

Comment: I even recreate the AVD, but it didn't work. I am wondering maybe it just dose not work in window 7.

Comment: 2.1 works in windows 7. jus try cerating a new one and check once

Comment: check in your emulator screen is that 3g connection symbol is available or not?

Comment: 3g symbol is available by the way

Answer (score 1):

1. > If you are wirelessly connected to the internet
   >
   > Go to control panel and disable your LAN card
2. > Home > Menu > Settings > Wireless Controls > Mobile Networks > Access Point Names
   >
   > Configure there
3. > Try creating a brand new emulator
4. > Try adding the followings params in "Additional Emulator Command Line 
   >   Option" in Eclipse (Run->Run Configuration -> Target Tab)
   >
   > -http-proxy http://ip:port -debug-proxy (ip=proxy address and 
   >   port=proxy's port)

Comment: I have tried it , and it didn't work. but it works when the target is android 2.2 and 2.3, just not in 2.2

Comment: Thanks a lot. I'll try it when I back home, i don't have wireless access right now